# Join with like and prevent multiple results

Tags: sql, db2

I want to join 2 tables and search value with like (only first 4 strings will be compared) in join. But the result should be only 1:1, I want to prevent multiple results for 1 entry in the main table.

tab1

| name |
| --- |
| jackson |
| michael |

tab2

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| JACK | 12345 |
| JACK X | 67890 |
| Micha | 12000 |
| Michael T. | 90000 |

Result

| name_tab1 | code_tab2 |
| --- | --- |
| jackson | 12345 |
| michael | 12000 |

I get more than one result for each entry in tab1.

```
Select * from tab1
left outer join tab2 on lower(substr(tab1.name,1,4) like '%'||substr(trim(lower(tab2.name)),1,4)||'%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH 
  TAB1 (NAME) AS 
(
VALUES
  'jackson'
, 'michael'
, 'Jack Daniels'
, 'Michelin'
)
, TAB2 (NAME, CODE) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('JACK',       '12345')
, ('JACK X',     '67890')
, ('Micha',      '12000')
, ('Michael T.', '90000')
)
SELECT A.NAME, B.CODE
FROM TAB1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE
(
SELECT B.CODE
FROM TAB2 B
WHERE 
  LOWER (SUBSTR (A.NAME, 1, 4)) 
  LIKE '%' || LOWER (SUBSTR (B.NAME, 1, 4)) || '%'
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) B ON 1 = 1
```

| NAME | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| jackson | 12345 |
| michael | 12000 |
| Jack Daniels | 12345 |
| Michelin | 12000 |

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=2f0fd0ab6aeeefee0c3e16c4fe1ed0ca)

Comment: As always, you are an asset to this community. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind what `code` to take, you can group by `name` and take max/min of `code`. Something like:

```
select tab1.name, max(tab2.code) 
from tab1
left outer join tab2 on lower(substr(tab1.name,1,4) like '%'||substr(trim(lower(tab2.name)),1,4)||'%'
group by tab1.name
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use max for char columns too?

Comment: sure, you can..

Comment: But, now because its grouping, I don't get for all duplicated entries in tab1 a result.

Comment: Normally, you don't keep exactly same records in the result as it's not much useful. If you are sure you need it, you can add an additional column to `tab1` that distinguishes between duplicate entries and add this column to the `group` clause.